# Java Button not clickable when exported

Tags: java

I have a JButton called lyricsButton, I added an actionListener to it but it doesn't want to work when I compile it. It works fine when testing but when I export as a runnable Jar nothing works I tried searching all over google and here already, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
JButton lyricsButton = new JButton(“LYRICS”)
lyricsButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(247, 148, 29), 2));
lyricsButton.setBackground(new Color(38, 38, 38));
lyricsButton.setOpaque(true);
lyricsButton.setFont(new Font("Montserrat", Font.PLAIN, 20));
lyricsButton.setForeground(new Color(247, 148, 29));
lyricsButton.setLocation(205, 300);
lyricsButton.setSize(375, 50);
backgroundImage.add(lyricsButton);


//LYRICS ACTION LISTENER
lyricsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  try {
   lyricsMainScreen.createLyricsScreen(null);
  } catch (IOException e2) {
   e2.printStackTrace();
  }
  mainFrame.dispose();
 }

});
```

Comment: Advice: Java code does not go into code snippets, and is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it’d look nicer this way

Comment: No worries. As you can probably see in my edit, there is a formatting for code in general which looks nicer without being odd. You just need to indent each line a certain number of spaces.

Comment: how you run jar ?